# How to get the object from Mono<Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I am using WebClient to communicate with other microservices. I want to get user from a remote UserService by id then I want to send this user information to another remote service the problem is I get the response as Mono but I have to get it as User object. i tried block() but it didn't work it always throws this error :`java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread`
here is a code

```java
    public User findUserById(String user_id){
        return webClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://localhost:7854/"+user_id)
                .retrieve().onStatus(httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpStatus),clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                .bodyToMono(User.class).block();
    }
```

I am using
Spring Boot 2.5.4
Java 11

Comment: What do you want to do with the `User` object? Can you add some code? There are a couple of options to do this but it really depends on your use case.

Comment: I just want to get that user then sent it in a post request to another service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the call to the other service is done in the following method:

```java
public Mono<Whatever> callToAnotherService(User user){
    // your logic here, I am assuming this is a WebClient call also.
}
```

And that you change the mentioned method to:

```java
public Mono<User> findUserById(String user_id){
    return webClientBuilder.build().get().uri("http://localhost:7854/"+user_id)
            .retrieve().onStatus(httpStatus -> HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(httpStatus),clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
            .bodyToMono(User.class);
}
```

You can now do the following in the class that calls both `findUserById` and `callToAnotherService`:

```java
findUserById("userId").flatMap(user -> callAnotherService(user)).subscribe();
```